# What is the size of HANDLE?

Tags: c, windows, structure, handle

For an exercise, I look at the `STARTUPINFO` structure. As you can see the last 3 elements has the type `HANDLE`.

So I want to know which size `HANDLE` has. Do somebody know the size of `HANDLE`?

Comment: Why not try sizeof(HANDLE) to find out.  I think it is a void*.

Comment: HANDLE is `void*` typically, so a pointer, which is 4 bytes (system dependent)

Comment: `HANDLE` is not in C99 and it is not in Posix. I guess it is a Windows thing.

Comment: Handles were meant to hide implementation details.  It is therefore *very* important to never ask this question.  Whatever answer you get today might well not be valid 10 years from now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Windows `HANDLE` type isn't a completely opaque type. Windows defines a couple of properties that you can depend on. The main one is the answer to your your question: it always of type `void *`.  From the [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#handle) entry on MSDN:

> **HANDLE**
>
> A handle to an object.
>
> This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
>
> `typedef PVOID HANDLE;`

Later on in the table you can see that [`PVOID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#pvoid) is defined as `void *`.

So a `HANDLE` has the same size as `void *`. Or in other words, it's 32 bits when using a 32-bit compiler and 64 bits when using a 64-bit compiler. You shouldn't need to hard code either of these values in to your code, instead just use `sizeof(HANDLE)`.

The other property of the Windows `HANDLE` type is very obscure, and is only barely documented: for kernel handles [the bottom two bits are always zero](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/21/358109.aspx). You shouldn't need to depend on this in your code, and hopefully you can see that you would never want to. I mention this for completeness and to emphasize how Microsoft has defined `HANDLE` to be more than just an internal implementation detail.

Answer (score 8):

The best answer is to use `sizeof(HANDLE)` to get this information. If I remember correct, `HANDLE` is usually implemented as a `typedef` for `void*` and is therefore probably 32 or 64 bits, but you shouldn't rely on this.

Hope this helps!